# How to add `strikethrough` to ribbon in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've right clicked the ribbon (under `bold` `italic` `underline` for what it's worth) and went to `customize the ribbon` but strike-through is not available to add to the ribbon. ...dead end?

[image]

Comment: I couldn't figure out any of these answers, i just clicked the [v] arrow on the bottom right of the `Basic Text` ribbon and check marked strikethrough for my highlighted text.

Comment: Why would this need an update for 2016? Ask a new question for 2016 since it's significantly different

Comment: @Peltier, my answer works for both Office 2010 and 2016. I added a screenshot for Outlook 2016 showing it has the strikethrough button.

Comment: @druciferre: this works when you have a separate window for composing an email. But not when editing from the main window. Is there a way to do so from the main window? If not could you add this precision to your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Outlook 365, right click on the ribbon, then select Customize the Ribbon.

On the left, select All commands, on the list Strike through will be listed.
Create a new group. Add the command to the newly created group.

[image]

Click OK.

[image]

The strikethrough command will now appear on the ribbon.
[image]

Comment: Nice! I don't think this was available in earlier versions. I'm pre-emptively changing answer to this one but I haven't tested it yet. If you know for sure that earlier versions disallowed this, can you give credit / link to the previously selected correct answer for older versions at the top of yours?  (hah! didn't see someone bountied the question)

Comment: @AppFzx "If you know for sure that earlier versions disallowed this" I don't know if previous versions disallowed it. I saw the bounty, replied based on my Outlook version :)

Comment: I'm really torn. I noticed I originally tagged the question outlook-2010. I changed the tag to generic outlook and this'll be the accepted one for the next 8 years.

Answer (score 12):

I just moved the **Font** and **Paragraph** groups from the **Format Text** tab over to the **Message** tab and removed the **Basic Text** group using **Customize the Ribbon**. Here's the result:

[image: Outlook New Mail Message Font and Paragraph]

Also works for Outlook 2013

[image: Outlook 2013 New Mail Message Font and Paragraph]

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Okay, I figured out what this meant. When you click "Customize Ribbon," you can expand the tabs on the right hand side, and drag groups from one to the other. Even though the contents of the default groups are not editable, you can still move them to a new tab.

Comment: So you can only do this for the Pop Out editor, is that right?

Answer (score 6):

By default it's in the **format text** tab on the ribbon above *font*.

If you want it on the **message tab** go to *Customize ribbon → Main tabs → New mail message* and  Create new group. From all commands on the left select strikethrough and *add* it to the new group.

Comment: That's roughly what I was trying but Strikethrough isn't in All Commands... I added a screenshot

Comment: Too complicated to find where to add as visible in the ribbon... I just gave up and used the Font popup out of the Basic Text section.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to bounty question:

> Looks like this is no longer possible with recent versions of outlook. A confirmation would be nice.

The Strike-through action is still available in Office 365,
but it is only displayed when customizing
the ribbon from the message editor.

Here it is when evoked from the editor:

[image]

And here is the result of including it in a custom group:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the command is only available from the message editor! This is really confusing IMHO.

Comment: @Peltier: I totally agree. On the other hand, this command can only be used in the editor.

Comment: I don't understand why you couldn't use it when editing an email in the main windows.

Answer (score 1):

i think @Emil was on the right track, why was the post down voted?

this is what i did

- right-click on **Message** ribbon, select **Customize the Ribbon**
- on **Choose command from**, select **All Tabs**
- expand **Format Text**, select **Font**
- click **Add** button, this will add Font to the New Mail Message tab, move up or down to where you want it
- you can now select **Basic Text** (on the right side) and click **Remove**

now Font, instead of Basic Text, will be available in the Message ribbon

use the same procedure if you want Paragraph also available

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way is to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar so it appears at the top of a New or pop-out reply email.

[image: Strikethrough on Quick Access]

Answer (score -1):

instead of adding individual buttons, remove the tab called "basic text"
add the tab called "Font"
add the tab called "Paragraph"

these tabs are not found in "all commands" they are found in "All tabs"